# Can a Raw SQL method that doesn't return data be called from the collection object?

Tags: codefluent

The following entity has a raw method that truncates (deletes) all records in a SQL database. I would like the method to be called from the collection object. Not a game killer if it can't but is it possible?

```
UserCollection.TruncateDatabase()

instead of

User.TruncateDatabase()
```

```html
  <cf:entity name="User" namespace="Amikids.ActiveDirectoryCache" categoryPath="/Amikids.ActiveDirectoryCache">
    <cf:property name="Id" key="true" />
    <cf:property name="DirectReports" typeName="{0}.UserCollection" relationPropertyName="ReportsTo" />
    <cf:property name="ReportsTo" typeName="{0}.User" relationPropertyName="DirectReports" />
    <cf:property name="UserInfo" typeName="{0}.Lightweight.UserInfo" />
    <cf:method name="TruncateDataBase">
      <cf:body text="RAW" rawText="TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.[User]" language="tsql" />
    </cf:method>
    <cf:method name="LoadByObjectGuid" body="LOADONE(guid objectGuid) WHERE UserInfo.objectGUID = @objectGuid" />
    <cf:method name="LoadByDistinguishedName" body="LOADONE(string distinguishedName) WHERE UserInfo.DistinguishedName = @distinguishedName" />
  </cf:entity>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use a raw delete method: https://www.softfluent.com/Documentation/Methods_Delete.html

```
 <cf:entity name="User">
    <cf:method name="TruncateDataBase">
      <cf:body text="DELETE() raw" rawBody="TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.[User]" language="tsql" />
    </cf:method>
  </cf:entity>
```

Comment: That did the trick. Just prefixing raw with DELETE() allowed me to call the method from the collection object